# Problem writing math equations using beamer class (Texnic Center)

Tags: beamer, math-mode, errors

I am making a beamer presentation with Texnic Center, and I came across a problem when writing math :

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}

First line of text\\
$\rightarrow$ The arrow works\\

\bigskip
$\Rightarrow$ This arrow works too

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Equation}

This doesn't work :\\

$a$
$a(t) = a0 + t a$ 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Error when creating PDF is `Cannot execute the command`

log-file says:

```
D:\Utilisateurs\jouissm\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecss0600.pk>!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file mathkerncmssi9): Font mathkerncmssi9 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The PDF isn't created because of the `$a$`: everything is fine when compiling things as `$\omega$` or `$\frac{1}{8}$`, but as soon as there is a letter in the math environment, like `$a$`, the error comes up. For now, I am using `$\text{a}$` in my equations, but it is not very convenient.

I work on Windows, with Miktex and Texnic Center.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please reduce your example as much as you can. I do not have the package `sfmath` here so I am already stuck. The shorter the example, the quicker you will get help. And if you put some effort into finding the culprit lines of code, you might see the problem by your self.

Comment: In my computer, it works, the equations can be displayed.

Comment: Which engine are you using? Also show the log-file. "It doesn't work" in not a useful problem description. Don't add edits as an answer. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Your MiKTeX is misconfigured; try running `updmap`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation